# How can I find contacts who have multiple home email addresses when on hold?

Tags: email

I would like to be able to easily check contacts with emails on hold designate other emails as primary, so the contacts continue receiving emails. I can make a profile to show primary and home, billing, other etc email addresses to quickly see which contacts have other email addresses. However, I can't figure out how to easily see if a contact has more than one home email address, as the search view only displays the first one. Is there any way to make this visible in a search view or even searchable?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any UI in vanilla civicrm install that provides a way to find multiple same email address or phone or address for a contact. You can either use Mysql knowledge to get all the duplicate records or create an extension to manage from UI

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this with the Data Processor extension, but it isn't pretty.

Use data sources email and contact in group (filter to a group you've created, perhaps with the mail bounce report), with match on contact ID = email contact. Fields: raw field value email, raw field value contact ID, raw field value email location type (optional).

Output a CSV and then you can find duplicate contact IDs with non-matching emails in this spreadsheet.

Comment: There is a better solution using the API explorer (this could possibly also be done in Search Kit not) here:
https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/38444/how-to-exclude-contacts-from-a-mailing-who-share-an-email-with-a-group-of-contac